# Query method for NHibernate with non-generic type parameter

Tags: nhibernate, syntax

We use NHibernate as our ORM. For the retrieval of most instances

```
session.Query<T>()
```

is just fine. How ever we have some instances where we want to specify the type during execution and pas it as a regular parameter something like:

```
session.Query(System.Type type)
```

Is this possible and if so what is the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't specify the type like that with `Session.Query<T>()`.

You can use `Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(type));` and then use the Criteria API.